# How do I get the prev data of a many to many field incase there is an Update

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to maintain a history of updates, I need to know how to get the previous data of a many to many field in the serializer update function

```
class User_Serializer(QueryFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
  updated_by = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True,required=False)
  class Meta:
        model = user
        fields = ["id",
                  "username",
                  "first_name",
                  "last_name",
                  "email",
                  "phone_number",
                  "groups","updated_by"]

  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
     updated_by=validated_data.pop("updated_by",None)
     for field,value in validated_data.items():
        new_value=value
        old_value=getattr(instance, field)
        if new_value!=old_value:
            insert = user_history(user_id=instance,field = field, previous_data =old_value, new_data = new_value,updated_by_id=updated_by)
            insert.save()
```

In here groups is the many to many field,
for some reason I'm getting auth.groups.None in old_value So,I also tried this

```
old_value=validated_data.get('groups', None)
```

and I got the new value instead
So, any help is much appreciated, ty!!

Comment: You did provide the context the code snippet runs in. Show us enough code to replicate the problem!

Comment: @KlausD., do let me know you need anything else!!

Answer (score 0):

```
prev=instance.groups.get_queryset()
```

I got the previous data, by using `get_queryset()`